# copy with a particular foldername

Tags: unix, xcopy

I wanted to copy, entire folder structure, with files(may be using xcopy). The criteria is that the folder structure should have a particular folder name. For example , I want to copy the entire folder structure, where folder name has "ABC"(all the folder structure should be copied, whereever "ABC" folder name is present - rest should not be). If it is not possible in xcopy, is there anything in UNix?

Comment: Just a note: in Unix you have "directories", not "folders".

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking. Could you give an example folder name of what you want to copy and what you don't?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood you correctly:

```
find directory/ -type d -name "ABC" && cp -r directory/ destination/
```

This will recursively copy `directory` to `destination` as long as `directory` contains a sub-directory called `ABC`.

Comment: Not sure, why. I get a "bash: [: too many arguments" error. Could it be because of the version?

Comment: There shouldn't have been any brackets. I'm not sure why I added those. I edited my answer.

Comment: This will actually copy everything recursively from directory to destination, whenever "ABC" is present. The source contains a lot of unwanted directories, I dont want to copy all the branches. I want to copy the braches, wherever "ABC" folder is present from source to destination. Sorry if my question was not clear.